# Ruby: How to check if a string contains multiple items?

Tags: ruby, string

I'm familiar with Ruby's `include?` method for strings, but how can I check a string for multiple things?

Specifically, I need to check if a string contains "Fwd:" or "FW:" (and should be case insensitive)

Example string would be: "FWD: Your Amazon.com Order Has Shipped"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
the_string =~ /fwd:|fw:/i
```

You could also use something like

```
%w(fwd: fw:).any? {|str| the_string.downcase.include? str}
```

Though personally I like the version using the regex better in this case (especially as you have to call downcase in the second one to make it case insensitive).

Comment: Thanks. Using the regex...how would you translate that line to say "if the_string does NOT have fwd:|fw:"?

Comment: And also, is there an official term for the use of `=~`

Comment: There's the `!~` operator which is exactly the same as negating the result of `=~`. Using `=~` is usually just referred to as matching against a regex. Don't know whether that counts as an official term.